# Specify location to clone GitHub Submodule

Tags: git, continuous-integration, git-submodules

My project build is failing because of the following error

```
C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet\sdk\7.0.404\NuGet.targets(400,5): error MSB3202: The project file "D:\a\MedbaseWebApi\MedbaseLibrary\MedbaseLibrary.csproj" was not found. [D:\a\MedbaseWebApi\MedbaseWebApi\MedbaseApi.sln]
```

I sought to solve the error by adding the Library in question as a submodule. And looking at the logs, the library is being cloned to a different directory path as below

```
Submodule 'MedbaseLibrary' (https://github.com/tanakamawere/MedbaseLibrary) registered for path 'MedbaseLibrary'
  Cloning into 'D:/a/MedbaseWebApi/MedbaseWebApi/MedbaseLibrary'...
  Submodule path 'MedbaseLibrary': checked out '3448be6ad145eda29cceafgfsdfg1641be'
```

The submodule is being cloned into an extra `MedbaseWebApi` folder. How can do I specify the directory I want the submodule to be cloned so that they are the same?